# IntelliJ Docker plugin use env file

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I am trying to execute a Docker run with an env file inside of IntelliJ.  Is there a way to run the image with this parameter supplied?  When going to the CLI settings it fails to execute by saying `--env-file is an invalid parameter`.

Comment: Did you check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167859 before asking?

Comment: @crazycoder i cannot believe i missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the `Docker` run configurations, select `Dockerfile` as the type.  Then enter `--env foo.env` (or equivalent) into the `Command line options` line.  The `Command preview` should now show the use of the environment file specified previously.